# Como criar ACL com Banco de Dados Externo no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, acl

A aplicação que estou fazendo já tem um banco de dados com os dados dos usuários. Os níveis que preciso é um 'Usuário comum', um 'Manager' e um 'Admin'.
A lógica de ter uma tabela user, role, role_user, permissions e permissions_roles, não daria certo, pois não teria como criar uma tabela role_user, pois o objetivo é que os dados do usuário sejam administrados em só banco de dados, a qual só tenho uma view de acesso. 
E tenho que mudar também a lógica do login, não tem como usar o attemp, pois as senhas dos usuários têm uma criptografia diferente do laravel, e não posso alterar isso no DB.

Eu pensei em criar três guards e no momento da autenticação, de acordo com a lógica definida para cada usuário, retorna o guard corresponde e trabalhar com ele na aplicação. tipo se o usuário é gerente de algum setor, então return Auth::guard('manager')->loginUsingId($user->id).

Só acredito que essa não seja a melhor forma, então como criar uma acl com banco de dados externos no laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faz um controller root e direciona o usuário logado pra ele e faz o ACL padrão criando as tabelas como ACL usa, vai funciona perfeitamente, só precisa verifica se o usuário do banco consegue criar tabelas.